# Adding an object to an array in a separate class

Tags: java, arrays, object

edit:
I am looking to pass HomeBuyers Objects to my homeBuyers ArrayList in my CreditUnion class. The this.homeBuyers.add function throws a "cannot find symbol" error. I have tried making the firstName, lastName, and creditScore vars static and passing the object in with HomeBuyers(HomeBuyers.firstName, HomeBuyers.lastName, HomeBuyers.creditScore). That avoided errors but did not add the object to the ArrayList.

```
public class LabProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    CreditUnion cu = new CreditUnion();

    cu.addHomeBuyer(new HomeBuyers("first","last",600));

    }

}

  public class HomeBuyers {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public int creditScore;

public HomeBuyers(String firstName, String lastName, int creditScore) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.creditScore = creditScore;
  }

  }

   public class CreditUnion {
     public ArrayList<HomeBuyers> homeBuyers;

public CreditUnion() {
    this.homeBuyers = new ArrayList<>();
      }


public void addHomeBuyer(HomeBuyers homeBuyers) {
     this.homeBuyers.add(HomeBuyers(firstName, lastName, creditScore));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This looks fine to me.  So what's your problem?  Please  add additional information to your question to be more clear what your issue is.  If you're getting an error message, you should include it in your question.

Comment: I'd recommend trying to change the name of the homebuyer variable that is being passed into the `addHomeBuyer()` function. I am not sure if this is the problem, but it makes reading the code and editing much much easier.

Comment: @TimMoore yeah, that wasn't helping. I have deleted the comment, my apologies.

Answer (score -1):

You have multiple problems here.

The right syntax for creating a new object is `new HomeBuyers(...)`. Not `HomeBuyers()`.

Separately, `firstName` doesn't exist as a variable in your `addHomeBuyer` method. The only variable that does exist is `homeBuyers`. You could write `homeBuyers.firstName`. However, you *already have* an instance of your class `HomeBuyers`. There is no need to make another one with identical values. `this.homeBuyers.add(homeBuyers)` would have done the job.

These questions are incredibly simplistic; stack overflow probably isn't the right venue. I suggest any of the many nice tutorials out there, they tend to take a little more time to explain things in an orderly fashion.